# React full screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullscreen

I need to develop a full-screen web app.
I have tried:

```js
import screenfull from "screenfull";

const HomePage = () => {

    if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
      screenfull.request();
    }
    
    return( 
    component...
    )
}
export default HomePage;
```

But when the page loads, it doesn't put it in full screen.
I also reported the same function in another route. (Component2 for example).

```js
import screenfull from "screenfull";

const Component2 = () => {

   if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
       screenfull.request();
   }
        
   return( 
   component...
   )
}
export default Component2;
```

On clicking anywhere on the HomePage the browser renders in Component2, after this event my app becomes full screen.

How do I get my app to start full screen from launch?

Comment: You could try react-full-screen from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-full-screen

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://web.dev/native-hardware-fullscreen/. You can use a useEffect to request fullscreen on the document body when it first loads. Hope that helps.